# AssertionError( AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: conpab 127.0.0.1)

Tags: python, flask, endpoint

Does anyone know why I use flask and type the URL : `127.0.0.1/testpge` to chrome and the error always show : `AssertionError( AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: conpab 127.0.0.1.`.  My code is under below :

```py
from flask import *

app=Flask(__name__, template_folder="C:\\Users\\Administrator\\")

@app.route("/testpge", endpoint='testpge')    
def pagee(name):
    con=100090909
    
    if con < 10 :
        @app.route("/conpa", endpoint='conpa')        
        def conpa():
            return "Conpa page is 000" 
    elif con > 10 :
        @app.route("/conpab", endpoint='conpab')
        def conpab():
            return "Conpa page is very big !"
    
    return "Test page 000"

if __name__ =="__main__" :
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1",port="80")
```

Comment: Why are you putting routes in an existing route?

Comment: I want to determine the condition.

Comment: Could I redirect myself view function, like this, return redirect(url_for("testpge"))??

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution

```
from flask import *

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/testpge/<string:name>", endpoint='testpge')    
def pagee(name):
    con=100090909
    
    if con < 10 :
        return redirect(url_for("conpa"))
    elif con > 10 :
        return redirect(url_for("conpab"))
    return "Test page 000"

@app.route("/conpa", endpoint='conpa')        
def conpa():
    return "Conpa page is 000" 

@app.route("/conpab", endpoint='conpab')
def conpab():
    return "Conpa page is very big !"

if __name__ =="__main__" :
    app.run()
```

---

URL: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/testpge/Akshay`

Output: `Conpa page is very big !`

Comment: it works then please vote up and mark it as accepted